# C# / WPF auto updater tool through Github

Tags: c#, wpf, github, continuous-deployment, auto-update

Sorry if this topic has been asked before but I'll explain anyway. I am working on software which allows a user to operate an industrial machine. Everything has been going smoothly, however we have come to a point where we have been asked to see how we can easily deploy new features to customers in a secure and fast way, and remotely due to practicality.

We have a private github repository to manage the code. Therefore I directly thought about an autoupdater which could retrieve the latest github release and compare to it the customers version. If the latest version is greater than the customers, it automatically downloads the newest features.

I have found some info about software that can do such a task, but my main question is: **Can it be done with a github repository?**

The software is a WPF application with C# and XAML.

Comment: You can check this package. I'm not sure if it's getting the data directly from the GitHub repository. However, it should work when you open a separate area in the repository and upload the .zip version of the relevant files and give the address of the rate. https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET

Comment: Thank you for the infos ! I've checked the package and it seems like it can do just what I am looking for ! 
Although I can't really understand where the xml file goes, it says that it needs to come from a server, and I can't really understand how this works... There's a changelog which has the github release and a Url which has the url to the zip archive

Comment: You can upload the xml file to any web server. (It also supports Json format.) The .zip file should contain the realese output of your project. It actually follows a simple path. Gets version information from xml file. Compares with the active application version. If there is a new version, it will download the .zip file. It closes the application and copies the contents of the .zip file to where the application files are.

Comment: Github'a yüklediğin herhangi bir xml dosyasının yolunu verebilirsin. This is the path to the sample xml file I found on github. https://gist.github.com/djangofan/3186223#file-test-xml     When you click on the Raw button, it gives you the address. I don't know if this address changes. You can use different free cloud servers to be more precise and secure.

Comment: Thank you for the infos ! Manage to do what I wanted through octokit ! The connection seemed pretty straight forward so i went with that. I'll keep your tips in mind for next time !

Comment: I have not used Oktokit before. I'll have a look, I'll definitely need it one day. Thank you. :)